# Adjust code to remove repeated filters in R

Tags: r, datatable

I would like to adjust the code below. Note that `(Id == idd, date2 ==........)` is repeated a few times, which is a waste of code. So, could you help me to adjust it so that it is used only once? The idea is that I can generate the same output table (`datas`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
  
df1 <- structure(
  list(Id=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"),
       date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-02","2021-07-04","2021-07-04","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5),
       DRM01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DRM02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DRM03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DRM04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DRM05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DRM06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DRM07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DRM08 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DRM09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DRM010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DRM011 = c(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
       DRM012 = c(0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5),DRM013 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0),DRM014 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

idd<-"1"
dmda<-"2021-07-04"
CategoryChosse<-"CDE"

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)

cols <- grep("^DRM0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)

med <- 
  dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
  ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Id, Category, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]

f2 <- function(nm, pat) grep(pat, nm, value = TRUE)
df2<-df1
nm1 <- f2(names(df2), "^DRM0\\d+$")
nm2 <- f2(names(med), "_PV")
nm3 <- paste0("i.", nm2)
setDT(df2)[med,(nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Id, Category, Week)]
SPV <- df2[, c('Id','date1', 'date2', 'Week','Category', nm2), with = FALSE]

mat1 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(Id==idd, date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
  select(starts_with("DRM0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
  pull(name)
(dropnames <- paste0(mat1, "_PV"))
 
SPV <- SPV %>%
  filter(Id==idd,date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
  select(-any_of(dropnames)) %>% data.frame()

if(length(grep("DRM0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
  SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
}

SPV<-as.data.table(SPV)

datas<-melt(SPV[Id == idd & date2 == ymd(dmda)][, 
lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = Category, 
.SDcols = patterns("^DRM0")],
id.var = "Category", variable.name = "name", value.name = "val")[, 
name := readr::parse_number(as.character(name))][]
colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("var1","var2")

datas<-datas[na.omit(datas[, .I[(as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [ 
  df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(var1)+1], .(Category)]$V1)]

datas

    > datas
       Category var1 var2
    1:      CDE    7    3
    2:      CDE    8    3
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this repeatedly.  in the first case, you are assigning back to `SPV` with the `filter`ed rows, so it is not clear why you need to do the `SPV[Id == ..` again

Comment: Thanks for reply! This is the first version of the code, so it was repeated. But I would like to adjust this, that is, use this filter only once, so as not to leave repeated code.

Comment: I am guessing that the second one with `melt` doesn't needs the filter

Comment: i.e. `> datas2<-melt(SPV[, 
lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = Category, 
.SDcols = patterns("^DRM0")],
id.var = "Category", variable.name = "name", value.name = "val")[, 
name := readr::parse_number(as.character(name))][]
colnames(datas2)[-1]<-c("var1","var2");  identical(datas, datas2)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Yes, good, and in `mat1` and `SPV`? It is repeated.

Comment: That case is when you are using `df2` and `df1` (df2 is a copy of df1) and SPV is created from df2.  Maybe you can create an object after filtering from 'df1', and then copy it to another one, so that it would have only a single filter step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we create the copy from the filter data, we can replace the 3 steps of filter to once

```
idd<-"1"
dmda<-"2021-07-04"
CategoryChosse<-"CDE"

df1_filt <- df1 %>%
      dplyr::filter(Id==idd, date2 == ymd(dmda), Category == CategoryChosse) 
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)


cols <- grep("^DRM0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)

med <- 
  dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
  ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Id, Category, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]

f2 <- function(nm, pat) grep(pat, nm, value = TRUE)
df2_filt <- copy(df1_filt)
nm1 <- f2(names(df2_filt), "^DRM0\\d+$")
nm2 <- f2(names(med), "_PV")
nm3 <- paste0("i.", nm2)
setDT(df2_filt)[med,(nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Id, Category, Week)]
SPV <- df2_filt[, c('Id','date1', 'date2', 'Week','Category', nm2), with = FALSE]

mat1 <- df1_filt %>% 
  select(starts_with("DRM0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
  pull(name)
(dropnames <- paste0(mat1, "_PV"))
 
SPV <- SPV %>%  
  select(-any_of(dropnames)) %>% data.frame()

if(length(grep("DRM0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
  SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
}

SPV<-as.data.table(SPV)

datas<-melt(SPV[, 
lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = Category, 
.SDcols = patterns("^DRM0")],
id.var = "Category", variable.name = "name", value.name = "val")[, 
name := readr::parse_number(as.character(name))][]
colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("var1","var2")
datas<-datas[na.omit(datas[, .I[(as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [ 
  df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(var1)+1], .(Category)]$V1)]
```

-output

```
> datas
   Category  var1  var2
     <char> <num> <num>
1:      CDE     7     3
2:      CDE     8     3
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it worked. Please just tweak your code. In `nm1` it was `df2`, but it is `df2_filt`